# Why do some paid apps have listing in /mnt/asec/ directory while others do not?

Tags: android, directory

I have noticed the /mnt/asec/ directory is used as a place for SOME paid apps to be stored, but not all.
What is the code to make sure my paid app is not listed here, but quietly placed into the /data/app-private/ like most others are?

(BTW, 
I have found that the "Move to SD Card" option occurred for Froyo(2.2) and possibly Gingerbread(2.3).  Back then these apps were split into res.zip and pkg.apk and placed into /mnt/asec/packageName/ when this was done. Apparently the reason for this directory has changed..?)

Answer (score 2):

It just started for me again about a month ago in Jellybean. I believe it's a gaggle thing.
I use LINK2SD, it's free to fix this behavior.
Run Link2sd click on the app and choose move to phone, even if it's on the phone, and link2sd will decrypt it and move it to the /data/data/* directory. From there you can link it to an external SD/TF card or move it to the SD card unencrypted.

Cheers
BuBu

Comment: Thanks, but I didn't give it an answer since I am looking for the reason why and the details of the changes so I can deal with different versions in an app.